# Java Query to return exact values from Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using the following query to search for documents:

```
QueryBuilder qb = matchQuery(
                "username_field",
                "user123"
            ); 
SearchResponse response = Client().prepareSearch("users_dashboard").setQuery(qb)
                .setSource("username_field")
                .execute().actionGet();
```

But I want it to return to me one document that contains the exact username. But what is currently returned is for an example: 
searching for `user123`
the following are all returned:

```
user123
user123 lastname
firstname user123
```

But I only want `user123` returned.

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) for exact match. I am assuming you are using `standard analyzer`(default) for the `user field` so you have following tokens in you `inverted index`

- user123    (doc 1, 2 ,3)
- firstname  (doc 3)
- lastname   (doc 2)

When you use `match query`, it will return all three documents. You need to map your user field as `index : not_analyzed` so that no analysis is performed. Your Inverted index will look like this.

- user123
- user123 lastname
- firstname user123

Then this query will give you desired results

```
QueryBuilder qb = termQuery(
                "username_field",
                "user123"
            );
```

Comment: how di I set the mapping to `not_analyzed` to an already existing index?

Comment: although you can set `not_anallyzed` to existing index, it wont affect the current values, better would be to create new index and then reindex everything.

Comment: I see. Another question, is setting more than one query will be query1 AND query2, or query1 OR query2 ?
Meaning, I wanna match a username that mentioned a set of words: `QueryBuilder qb1 = termQuery("user.screen_name", Username);
        QueryBuilder qb2 = matchQuery("text", Keywords);` and return the count of documents. Will ES treat this as `Username AND Keywords`, or `Username OR Keywords`?

Comment: you can do that will [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/bool.html) must means AND, should means OR. also please dont ask different question in comment to keep this thread clean.